# How to Set "Google Analytics" in (base.html.twig)

Tags: symfony, twig

i'm setting google analytics in my Symfony Website,  i'm using ftp to edit the files. I have deleted the cache folder also, but still its not woking.

I have already the code in /public_html/app/Resources/views in base.html.twig

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv=" ">
<meta name=" ">
<title> </title> 
<meta name="description" content=" "> 
<meta name="keywords" content=" ">
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src=" "></script>
<script>
 //
</script>

</head>
```

i expect that it should be display, but in actual its not working.

Answer (score 0):

What's your Symfony version? In recent versions of Symfony you should store templates in:
*root_app_directory\templates\base.html.twig*

And later use it in other file like homepage.html.twig by:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
```

You can check Symfony documentation and check [how to use templates](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating.html)

Also you can check if everything works correctly by adding anything other than Google Analytics to your base.html.twig and check if that appears on your website.